# Shell script to sum number between "nmemb:(" and ")"

Tags: shell

I have a file called "X" which has a lot of nmemb:(123) , nmemb:(56789) , ....

```
cat X | grep -o 'nmemb[^_]*$'
```

output like :

```
nmemb:(16384)
nmemb:(16384)
nmemb:(16384)
nmemb:(5608)
nmemb:(10776)
nmemb:(16384)
nmemb:(16384)
nmemb:(16384)
nmemb:(16384)
nmemb:(16384)
```

How can I sum these number between "nmemb:("  &  ")" ? like :

```
cat X | grep -o 'nmemb[^_]*$' | doSumBetweenBracket()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Like this:

```
$ grep -oP 'nmemb:\(\K\d+' X | paste -sd '+' | bc
```

or

```
grep -oP 'nmemb:\(\K\d+' X | awk '{c+=$1}END{print c}'
```

or with `GNU` `awk` only (no pipes)

```
awk '/memb:\([0-9]/{match($0, /[0-9]+/, a);c+=a[0]}END{print c}' X
```

##### Output

```
147456
```